# Python `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` `cosine_similarity` or `cosine_distance` theoretical range

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

Cosine similarity/distance should be bounded between -1 and +1. Yet, `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` gives values > +1. Can anyone explain this behaviour please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pairwise`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) default distance is Euclidean which is not bounded from above, hence you should not be surpised to see some values greater than 1.